# How to remove word says: from comments of wordpress latest 4.4 version

Tags: php, wordpress, include, comments, cpanel

Recently, i have updated my wordpress version 4.4..

i have made some changes in comment list of wordpress older version...

but due to update my all changes had lost...

now, i am trying to find the word (says) in wordpress comment list....in new version...

but i am unable to find it...

in older version this code was there into comment-template.php file

```
<div class="comment-author vcard">
                        <?php if ( 0 != $args['avatar_size'] ) echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>
                        <?php printf( __( '%s <span class="says">says:</span>' ), sprintf( '<b class="fn">%s</b>', get_comment_author_link() ) ); ?>
                    </div>
```

but now into newer version i am unable to find it.

please tell me where is now this coding into newer version. it is not there into comment-template.php

or how to find [ says: ] word.

Comment: does your editor not have find/search functionality?

Comment: i am searching this term into cpanel /public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php

Comment: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=says&type=Code

Comment: Thanks a lot...mevius....

it was there in class-walker-comment.php.....